# eval using current function's namespace

Tags: scheme, eval, racket

The following racket function produces the error:

```
reference to undefined identifier: val
```

This is because the eval function looks at the global namespace,  not the local function's namespace.  How do I trick eval into using the local function's namespace?

```
(define some-eval!
  (lambda (val row col)
    (eval (list 'define 'ttboard '(list-builder val row col))) (current-namespace) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `ttboard` ahead of time and then `set!` it:

```
(define ttboard #f)
(define create-board
  (lambda (val row col)
    (set! ttboard (list-builder val row col))))
```

That way, you can clearly tell that `ttboard` is a global variable, rather than having its definition obscured in an eval'd clause.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is specific to Racket.  In general different Scheme implementations have various approaches to this problem, but in almost all cases you will not get `eval` to handle local bindings like you're trying to do.  But specific to the Racket case, you should read the [evaluation section](http://pre.plt-scheme.org/docs/html/guide/eval.html) in the Racket guide -- it explains why things aren't working like you want them to, and it shows how to get the module scope to work.

Just as a quick summary -- the reason local bindings are not visible to `eval` is that this means that `(lambda (x) x)` and `(lambda (y) y)` cannot be compiled to the same function, since the names can make a difference.  You could argue that the compilation could depend on whether `eval` is used inside the function or not -- but that's something that cannot be determined at compile-time.  For example:

```
(define (foo f) (let ([x 1]) (f 'x)))
(foo eval)
```

In this case, there is no way for the compiler to tell that `foo` is ever going to be called with `eval`.

Finally, there are similar difficulties in other languages that try to tackle `eval`.  For example, in JS, `eval` is a magical thing that can affect the way a function is compiled, so something like:

```
function foo(x) { alert("x = " + eval("x")); }
```

will actually work -- but it requires `eval` to be physically present in the body of the function. If that's not done, then things can break. For example, this code:

```
function foo(x,f) { alert("x = " + f("x")); }
foo(123,eval);
```

works for me in Fx, but fails in Chrome, saying that `x is not defined`. And if that's not enough to demonstrate the mess, consider this:

```
function foo(x,f) { alert("x = " + f("x")); }
var x = 456;
foo(123,eval);
```

shows 456 in Chrome *and* in Fx.

Comment: Thanks for the response,  but I'm still at a loss.  I can't get this code to interpret without using a global define,  is there another way?  Also i read that racket article,  and it pisses me off that they completely ignored the obvious case that i am in.

Comment: (1) Read again my short explanation above about why it is not possible to do that; (2) Read again the guide page -- it certainly does talk about "your obvious case", in fact, it's exactly what the first section (15.1.1) is talking about, and that section has a nice conclusion about what makes it impossible.

Comment: @Eli Barzilay  yes exactly both of these sources are only explaining that what i'm trying to do is impossible unless i do a global define.

Comment: @Rook: Well, I suppose you could write your own Scheme interpreter from scratch to handle `eval` the way you want. This is only "impossible" for certain values of impossible.

Comment: @erjiang right, or i could just use an already existing flavor of scheme that has better documentation.

Comment: @Rook: Eli's point is that the documentation clearly explains why Racket will not `eval` the expression in its local scope.

Comment: You'd be hard pressed to find a Scheme with better documentation than Racket.

Comment: @eli, In Firefox 4.0, your second example is an error.  The difference is that direct eval (when eval is literally applied), you get access to the lexical environment, but when eval is used in higher-order fashion, you only get access to the global environment.

Comment: Rook: in addition to what others said -- you'd be hard pressed to find a scheme implementation that makes it *possible* at all -- documentation or not.  (And BTW, the suggestion to write your own interpreter seems exaggerated, but it's perfectly possible to write some macros that "expose" the lexical environment in a way that is accessible.)

Comment: Sam: Yeah, that was my guess -- but I was too lazy to look up what they spec it to do...

Comment: Eli, these days I don't have to look it up ... :(

Comment: "the reason local bindings are not visible to eval is that this means that (lambda (x) x) and (lambda (y) y) cannot be compiled to the same function, since the names can make a difference." Can you expand on this? I thought the asker wanted free variables to refer to the lexical env, but you are talking about variables bound inside the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, for what you want to do, it may be enough to set the values of `val`, `row`, and `col` at expression-composition time, rather than have the interpreter grab the values of `val` et al. at eval-time (impossible in Racket).

```
(define some-eval!
  (lambda (val row col)
    (eval (list 'define 'ttboard `(list-builder ,val ,row ,col)))
          (current-namespace)))
```

Note that there is almost certainly a nicer, cleaner way to accomplish what you are trying to do without `eval`, unless, of course, you are doing this to practice using `eval`.

Comment: I've actually tried this code segment,  and it doesn't work because the contents returned by list-builder is then undefined. Actually an eval is required because a (define) within a function will define that variable only within the function's namespace and not in the global namespace.   The software requirement does state that i need to modify the global define of ttboard.   +1 for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there's no way to access the lexical environment with `eval`, as Eli points out.  However, I believe that this workaround will do what you want:

```
#lang racket/load

(define some-eval!
  (lambda (val row col)
    (namespace-set-variable-value! 'val val)
    (namespace-set-variable-value! 'row row)
    (namespace-set-variable-value! 'col col)
    (eval (list 'define 'ttboard '(list-builder val row col)) 
          (current-namespace))))
(define list-builder list)
(some-eval! 1 2 3)
(display ttboard)
```